# MYSQL Insert results of concat

Tags: mysql, insert, concatenation

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
ID     ORDER_ID     QTY     VALUE     
1       153          1        0
2       476          1        0
3       453          9        1
4       719          2        2
```

With this table, I have to concat " " to the values of QTY and VALUE and then store it back in the table, so it can look like this (Both, `qty` and `value` are TEXT):

```
ID     ORDER_ID     QTY     VALUE     
1       153         "1"      "0"
2       476         "1"      "0"
3       453         "9"      "1"
4       719         "2"      "2"
```

To concat the values, I use the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT('"',qty,'"') qty, 
CONCAT('"',`VALUE`,'"') VALUE
FROM `myTable`;
```

Now, when I try to use:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`order_id`, `qty`, `value`) 
SELECT `order_id`, CONCAT('"',qty,'"') , CONCAT('"',value,'"')  
FROM `1.1`;
```

This basically blanks my entire table.

However, if I use a single concat, I can get the desired output stored but the rest of the fields are blank.

```
 INSERT INTO `myTable` (`qty`) 
    SELECT CONCAT('"',qty,'"')
 FROM `1.1`;
```

Sorry if this is a newb question but I did try to search no to avail.

Thank You.

Comment: but... but... why would you do this? What possible use case can there be for adding quotes around the values? (Also, `INSERT` is only used to append NEW rows to the DB. Editing existing rows requires use of the `UPDATE` statement)

Comment: Totally stupid thing to do. Don't!

Comment: Yes...I see why most people would complete flip out about the naming. The reason why I needed the quotes was because I had to mimic a table where output was via JSON and had concatenation of "item":"qty". Since it was just easier to take old tables and transform them into the new scheme, I "brute forced" the table. Sorry =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, why do you need to make `qty` or `value` into a string?

First, alter your datatype into varchar. Second, the `INSERT` statement means adding new rows to your table, so if you want that kind of result, you need to use the `UPDATE` statement.

In your code:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`order_id`, `qty`, `value`) 
SELECT `order_id`, CONCAT('"',qty,'"') , CONCAT('"',value,'"')  
FROM `1.1`;
```

Does this mean that your table name is 1.1? I think it is not a proper way of naming tables.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The 1.1 was only to keep track outside DB when posting question - that is not the naming scheme of my table.